# Row takes over the entire space

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to achieve this.

Expected Widget

[image]

Current Widget

[image]

That means Row of "Park and Change" should take up the width of "Guaranted Rate Field" text. But I am unable to achieve the expected widget.

Here's the code :

```
Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  Icon(
                                    Icons.account_balance,
                                    size: 16,
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    width: globalMarginHorizontal / 2,
                                  ),
                                  Text("League",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Theme.of(context)
                                              .textTheme
                                              .subtitle1
                                              .color,
                                          fontSize: 15))
                                ],
                              ),
                              Text("Change",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor))
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: globalMarginVertical / 6,
                        ),
                        Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Text(
                              "Guaranteed Rate Field",
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
                            ))
                      ],
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this:

1. Using Spacer
   : Spacer widget will take remaining area of a row. So put it where you want the space like at 3rd position in row
2. Otherwise give MainAxisAlignment as spacebetween and put the other content inside a new row

I Would prefer using Spacer

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in two ways:

1. By using `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` property
2. By using an `Expanded` widget
3. By using `Spacer` widget

By using `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween`

```
Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, // New <---------------------
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Icon(
                    Icons.account_balance,
                    size: 16,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  Text("League",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1.color,
                          fontSize: 15))
                ],
              ),
              Text(
                "Change",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        Container(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Text(
              "Guaranteed Rate Field",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
            ))
      ],
    )
```

By using `Expanded` widget

```
Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(  // New <-----------------
              child: Row(  // New <-----------------
                children: [
                  Icon(
                    Icons.account_balance,
                    size: 16,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  Text("League",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1.color,
                          fontSize: 15))
                ],
              ),
            ),  // New <-----------------
              Text(
                "Change",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        Container(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Text(
              "Guaranteed Rate Field",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
            ))
      ],
    )
```

By using `Spacer` widget

```
Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Icon(
                    Icons.account_balance,
                    size: 16,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  Text("League",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1.color,
                          fontSize: 15))
                ],
              ),
              Spacer(),  // New <------------------
              Text(
                "Change",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        Container(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Text(
              "Guaranteed Rate Field",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
            ))
      ],
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working. your code is producing the same output as current.I know these widgets but this case is a bit tricky. There are 2 rows in the column and I wanted that both the rows should take up the size of the longest row inside a column.

Comment: I already ran this code in dartpad & checked, then I posted this answer. It is working as expected.